# Is it possible to build a NAS enclosure?

Tags: nas, computer-building

Can one assemble a Network Attached Storage solution without the need to integrate a other computer components; to just have an enclosure powering multiple disk drives with a USB/Ethernet port routing access externally?

What about [Direct-Attached Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-attached_storage) or [Storage Area Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_Area_Network) solutions? Would they do what I want?

Comment: Interesting question +1. I'm hoping someone more technical than me will answer too

Answer (score 1):

You mean like a network attached USB Hard Drive? You *can* attach it say to a router with USB, but it's not going to perform like [Network Attached Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) because the files will not be managed by a file manager, rather the clients will need to connect to the drive, mount it and stream it in blocks. Will it work? Yes. Is it a recommended solution? No

What about setting up the HDDs onto an existing computer and having a file share setup?

Answer (score 0):

If high performance isn't a must you can buy a NAS appliance like this one:

[NAS Adapter](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/usb-to-nas-adapter-usb-rj45-port-107012) or this [NSK 330](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/standalone-bittorrent-bt-client-usb-nas-ftp-samba-printer-upnp-sharing-network-lan-server-26320).

I have the second one and you can install a new firmware (SnakeOS) with more features like a bittorrent client